# Error: GET http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js net::ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING, on Ember.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js

I am just getting started with Ember.js at v2.9.0, followed the tutorial on their page https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.9.0/tutorial/ember-cli/, all good, save for one detail: Whenever I tried to refresh or load the development web app on Chrome browser after executing `ember server` on the cmd, the app would not load in browser and provide the following error most of the time (there were other errors as well but seem to be related to this one):

`GET http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js net::ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING`

, and one of the related errors is:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at application.js:1`

I have searched for this specific error but without luck, I tried some fix hints found, such as clearing some persistent data with the `netsh` command, doing an `npm cache clean` `bower cache clean`, deleting the *node_modules* and the *bower_components* folders and reinstalling dependencies; also ensuring that there was no weird proxy configuration in my LAN settings, etc.

I have encountered this error while following the tutorial, and it would kind of be bypassed by refreshing the browser a few times until the app displayed. That was before, but now the refresh does not work when working on an existing application.

I am on:

Windows 10

ember-cli v.2.9.1

node.js LTS v.6.9.1

I need to get going with this rather soon, so any hint to resolve this issue is appreaciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your tutorial link is broken.

Comment: Right, I fixed it now, @RyanZim. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a conflicting process running... Are you working over a VPN? If so, take a look at https://superuser.com/questions/893908/err-invalid-chunked-encoding-from-chrome

Comment: In this particular case, I am not using a VPN connection when serving the site through ember, but will dig deeper on that, as I have to connect to vpn for other tasks.

Comment: As a quick check, follow [these steps](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96815?hl=en). If it resolves the issue, it was a weird VPN thing.